# Removing the surface layer from ceramic tile

Tags: removal, ceramic-tile

I have green tile in my bathroom with pink accents.  Is it possible to remove the pink using muriatic acid (concentrated HCL)?  I have a background in clinical and chemistry laboratory sciences and am more than aware of the safety gear and precautions required.  Has anyone used this approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "accents"?

Comment: You want to remove the glaze from the ceramic backing? Egads.

Answer (score 2):

My mom used to do ceramics the accents are small bits of pigment in the glaze these are baked and become part of the surface, removing the accents would ruin the seal of the glaze. Replacing the tile would be a better way to go than trying to etch just the accents as this will also discolor the green part of the glaze.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the accents in question are under or part of the glaze. Glaze on ceramics is basically glass melted on to the surface of the ceramic. This gives you two problems.

1. Most acids (including HCl) won't touch glass.
2. If you do succeed in removing the glaze you will have removed what seals the tile against water and gives it a smooth surface for cleaning.

Comment: And #3, there's not really a way to replace damaged glaze that would come close to the original durability.